# apache2.4 virtual host blocking access with authz_core log, even though authz not configured

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-wsgi, mod-authz-host

So I'm getting `403: Forbidden` errors on one of my apache2.4 virtualhosts.

What's interesting, is that `/var/log/apache2/error.log` reports:

`authz_core:error] [pid 4878:tid 140394394269440] [client 10.214.154.19:33009] AH01630: client denied by server configuration`

And....  While I do have other Virtualhosts which use authz (for subversion hosting primarily) I disabled all of them except the one I'm having issues with, restarted Apache, and there is no discernible difference.

Here is my Apache2 sites-available file which, even though I have disabled all other host configs, and stripped my config down to a minimum, is still denying access.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  WSGIScriptAlias /example /data/example/example.wsgi

  <Directory /data/example>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Furthermore, just to verify It's not my wsgi script, I replaced the script with:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type','text/html')])
        return ['<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>']
```

And that doesn't make any discernible difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated in [Apache "Client denied by server configuration", despite allowing access to directory (vhost configuration)](https://serverfault.com/questions/418101/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration-despite-allowing-access-to-direc) the issue is that Apache 2.4 has changed the way authorization configuration is done. The authz_core module is actually built-in, which seems to be a source of confusion.

If you simply remove the Order and Allow lines, things should work as expected. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html for details.

Comment: Thank you.  For anyone in the future:  Remember to pay attention to the ordering of your Aliases and VirtualHosts.  I had actually tried over a dozen different authentication setups, but I had a second issue that was preventing me from realizing that this would have fixed this particular issue.