# 403 following Modoboa-apache2.4 setup

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, email-server

Machine details:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Apache2 2.4.41
- Mariadb 15.1 (don't think it's
  pertinent)

I recently followed a guide to install modoboa (mail server) on a fresh server. The default setup install with nginx which at the end did work (at least the page `mail.mysite.com` loaded).

After disabling nginx and enabling apache2, I created `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/modoboa.conf` as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mail.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/modoboa/instance/

  Alias /media/ /srv/modoboa/instance/media/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /sitestatic/ /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/modoboa/instance/instance/wsgi.py

  # Pass Authorization header to enable API usage:
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

Following a certbot command `sudo certbot --apache --agree-tos --redirect --hsts --staple-ocsp --email me@gmail.com -d mail.mysite.com` the following was generated:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/apache2/stapling_cache(128000)
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mail.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/modoboa/instance/

  Alias /media/ /srv/modoboa/instance/media/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /sitestatic/ /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/modoboa/instance/instance/wsgi.py

  # Pass Authorization header to enable API usage:
  WSGIPassAuthorization On


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mysite.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
SSLUseStapling on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now when I try to connect to `mail.mysite.com` I just get a 403 forbidden error. Looking into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I see:

```
[Thu Aug 19 20:52:04.159144 2021] [core:notice] [pid 6213] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Aug 19 20:52:06.296969 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 6216] [client 74.206.137.114:49866] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /srv/modoboa/instance/instance/wsgi.py
```

Looking around I saw things like [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/661644/apache2-4-virtual-host-blocking-access-with-authz-core-log-even-though-authz-no). Following those I did change what I had before `Order deny,allow  Allow from all` to the setup shown above, yet I still have the same error.

Looking with `ls-ls /srv/` I see `drwxr-xr-x  7 modoboa  modoboa  4096 Aug 19 19:42 modoboa` which I believe shows modoboa can do it's own thing fine.

Given this worked when nginx was enabled, I feel like it's something to do with my apache2 configs, but I really just can't tell what it is. If anyone has some insight on the matter I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing this definition inside your vhost configs

```
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/instance>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

I would also not count on the user permissions being modoboa:modoboa for files, which apache needs to serve. You could change them to the default ones.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/modoboa
```

Comment: When adding this I get a 500 error on page load. In the apache error logs I get the error (in hastebin: https://hastebin.com/enobumilen.yaml). Which clearly is saying it needs django but I'm not even sure why, or where I would go abouts setting that up. I can't really see what I would do from here except maybe make a global pip3 install of django?


edit: Following a `sudo pip3 install django` I then get still a 500 with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instance'` in the errors.log file. This feels like a rabit hole that may not be the good one to go down?

Comment: It looks like there are python modules missing. Install them globally and see where you can go from there. At least we can be sure that the wsgi.py file is being served by apache.

Comment: Is there nothing for a recommended modoboa setup for this? I keep adding more modules, and then get to no module `instance.settings` which I only really see [this github issue](https://github.com/modoboa/modoboa/issues/1276) which is no longer usable since this is for python2 and also activate_this.py does not exist anymore in that path.